# What is the difference between 7-day yield and gross 7-day yield of a money market fund?

Tags: yield, money-market

Federated Hermes Government Reserves Fund Class A (GRAXX) has a 7-day yield of 3.96 while it has a gross 7-day yield of 4.84. I wonder what is the difference between two attributes and how are these calculated.
https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/mutual-fund/graxx

I found few articles that explains difference between subsidized and unsubsidized 7-day yields but could not found any article on gross and regular 7-day yield.

Comment: Gross 7-day yield in % (simple), calculated by adding expense ratio to current 7-day yield (annualized). You can Google "gross 7day yield" (including the "") to get plenty of results like https://data.nasdaq.com/databases/NFN/documentation